# how to relay same table header on multiple tables?

Tags: tables, comparison

So I have multiple comparison tables on one page. They all have the same companies names at the top for comparison on each table. Each section which has a table is comparing different data sets. How can I eliminate the need of repeating the company name on every table? I was thinking about a sticky header but since each table is broken into different sections it leaves me in the same boat (plus there's paragraphs of text between each table).

Answer (score 1):

It would work to have a sticky header that appears in the proximity of tables and dissapears when text or other elements are shown in the page.